# Does DeVoe's effigies power affect corpses?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

When we see a fully powered DeVoe attack an A.R.G.U.S. center in the Flash, we see him reanimate a few downed agents.  These agents make sounds like zombie, and the way they were reanimated was similar to how Black Bison (can't remember the name) controlled effigies.  Was it ever established she could move around bodies as well, or was this another power being used?

Comment: I suspect it was Brain Storm's mind control powers that was being used at that point, not that of Black Bison's. 

I don't recall anyone being reanimated (which implies having been killed) as much as perhaps being knocked out and taken over while sleeping.

Comment: @VBartilucci In the scene where he's attacking, it doesn't look like they're knocked out. Especially since he starts out the fight scene by shrinking a guard and crushing them under his shoe.